Change of simultaneity with speed and direction
I am a physics enthusiast.  I was watching a video by Professor Brian Greene on YouTube. He said that when an alien in a distant galaxy is at rest relative to Earth, he will see the present of earth. But if he were to go in the opposite direction of the Earth in a rocket, he would see past events on  Earth. My question is, how do we know this from math of SR.

Please update your question with a link to the specific video and identify the time of the statement

If Brian Greene really said it in this way, he's being rather loose with the usage of the word "see".
Here is the important part to understand: when we talk about observers and reference frames, we're never talking about a single alien or an entity somewhere, and what he/she/it are measuring locally all by themselves.
Rather, an inertial reference frame or an inertial observer (or a coordinate system) corresponds to an essentially infinite collection of synchronized clocks and measuring rulers, all spread across space and all having the same state of motion, all the while recording events via pairs comprising of $(t,\vec{x})$ where $t$ stands for time and $\vec{x}$ spatial position.
So what Professor Greene really should have said is:
"When the frame of reference of the alien is at rest with respect to earth, events which are simultaneous on earth will also be measured as simultaneous in the reference frame of the alien". Sure, doesn't sound as fancy, but much more accurate.
Similarly, he should have said:
"When the frame of reference of the alien is moving away from the earth, its hyperplane of simultaneity tilts so that the observers in his frame that correspond to the spatial locations of the earth, in fact correspond to the earth in earlier times than the one observed in a reference frame that's at rest with respect to the earth".
Sounds complicated? Perhaps at first, but let's see if we can clarify it a bit with some math as per your request:
The Lorentz transformation tells us how to relate times of inertial frames in relative motion. Let's confine ourselves to motion along one spatial dimension, because it suffices here for the conceptual understanding.
$(t_{\text{alien}},x_{\text{alien}})$ will be the alien's frame coordinates, $(t_{\text{earth}},x_{\text{earth}})$ will be the earth's frame coordinates. So:
$$ t_{\text{earth}} = \gamma(t_{\text{alien}}-vx_{\text{alien}}) \tag{1}$$
Now $\gamma$ as you may know is the Lorentz factor, it is defined by the relative speed $v$ between the frames as $\gamma=\left(1-v^2\right)^{-1/2} $.
So, in the first case the alien is at rest with respect to earth. You can check that implies $v=0$ and hence $\gamma=1$, and we find from $(1)$:
$$ t_{\text{earth}} = t_{\text{alien}},$$
as expected.
Now the more interesting case, if $v>0$ then you can check $\gamma>1$, and $(1)$ can be written as:
$$ t_{\text{earth}} = \gamma t_{\text{alien}}-\gamma vx_{\text{alien}} $$
It still isn't clear from this that the alien's frame observes earlier times than before. Let's rearrange this expression a bit:
\begin{align*} t_{\text{earth}} &= t_{\text{alien}}\left(\gamma-\gamma v \frac{x_{\text{alien}}}{t_{\text{alien}}}\right) 
\\&= t_{\text{alien}}\left(\gamma-\gamma v^2\right) 
\\&= \frac{t_{\text{alien}}}{\gamma}
\end{align*}
Where in the first step we've used the fact that $\large\frac{x_{\text{alien}}}{t_{\text{alien}}}=v$, is just the relative speed between the frames again. In the last step we've just applied the definition of $\gamma$ mentioned before.
So we see that if for example $t_{\text{earth}}=2024\ \text{AD}$, since $\gamma > 1$ the corresponding time $t_{\text{alien}}$ will now be $t_{\text{alien}} > 2024$. In other words, doing the analysis from the alien's frame we see it will measure the events occurring in $2024\text{ AD}$ only later relative to when he was at rest. In other words he is indeed now, very loosely speaking again, "observing earth's past" relative to what he observed before, when he was at rest with respect to the earth.
Finally, important to note is that everywhere in this post I've taken the speed of light as in natural units, i.e. $c=1$, to make the equations simpler. It's particularly useful when trying to understand things conceptually rather than cranking actual numbers.
Secondly, you can also see this answer of mine where I also work out a very similar scenario via a spacetime diagram. There are many posts here that make use of these diagrams in similar situations, I happen to remember this one because I've written it quite recently. Hope all of this helps!

The answer is very simple and no related to time traveling. The light has a fixed speed. The more far you are more time elapsed. Therefore the alien doesn't see the present, but a past that can be measured how much time elapsed. But if you include relativity, time reverses when you travel more fast than light, in some way unknown yet (for while light limits up all velocities).
However if you have a ingenious trick to bypass that limit, you can make a mental experiment: I am here waiting for a show in two weeks, but I am bored and go out there to scramble. If I can go fast, I gain time, arriving in others places, others events out there in universe so before the deadline. But you didn't mention details, perhaps the first explanation is the one.
Stephen Hawking explored traveling faster than light in his book "A New History of Time" in English I think. Relativity says that different observers nor need agree about order of events through the space. You see that briefly in cited book.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
